# How to know, how much I scrolled in a UIScrollview?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

Hey guys I have an image of 3200x480 and I have also 4 tabs. All the Views in the 4 tabs have the same image.

What I want to do is that when I scroll lets say the first view to any point all the others views in the other tabs also scroll their images to the same position? Any tips?

I tried with contentOffset and contentInset, but I wasn't able to do that.

How can I know at what point my scrollview is showing in the ipod so I can get that gcpoint and send it to the other views...
Thanks

Carlos Vargas

Answer (score 2):

UIScrollViewDelegate's `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`
combined with `[scrollView contentOffset]` and `[scrollView setContentOffset:]` should handle what you've described.

Please edit and sample code for what you've tried already.